# bundling breaks some styling

Tags: c#, bundling-and-minification

i have not been able to figure out the solution so far, been looking here on stackoverflow and google but to no avail.

My issue, i have a website with bundleConfig.cs, where i bundle all my stuff. 
When `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;` 
is set, it works without issue. 
But if i set it to true, or remove it. Some of my styling just does not work.

I have no idea how to debug that..

My bundle:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {

            // Third party Scripts
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/third-party-scripts") { Orderer = orderer }
                .Include("~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/Slick/slick.min.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/Masonry/masonry.pkgd.min.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/Imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.js") // do i need?
                .Include("~/Scripts/SimpleLightbox/simple-lightbox.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/Calendar/fullcalendar.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/Datatables/datatables.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/Growl/jquery.growl.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/PageComments/pageComments.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/CookieConsent/CookieLogic.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/Popper/popper.min.js")

            );

            // Custom Scripts
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/custom-scripts") { Orderer = orderer }
                .Include("~/Scripts/Custom/custom.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/Custom/Slick-init.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/Custom/masonry-init.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/Custom/lightbox-init.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/Custom/fullcalendar-init.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/Custom/datatables-init.js")
            );
            // Material-Kit
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/material-kit-scripts") { Orderer = orderer }
                .Include("~/Scripts/Material-kit/bootstrap-material-design.min.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/Material-kit/material-kit.js")
            );
            // Material-Kit Front Styles 
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/material-kit-styling") { Orderer = orderer }
                .Include("~/Content/Scss/Vendors/Material-kit/material-kit.css")
                .Include("~/Content/Scss/Vendors/Material-kit/Custom-overwrites.css")
                .Include("~/Content/Scss/Vendors/Growl/growl.css")
            );


        }
```

So far i can see that Custom-overwrites.css does not work when it is being minified..

Any tips for solutions or how to proceed from here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the custom-overwrites.css was corrupt in some way.. 
So created a new custom.css file and imported that into material-kit.css
And now it works.

Answer (score 1):

In the **RegisterBundles** function add the following as the first line:

```
bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
```

Also make sure all your min files are valid files (css and js).

Comment: added this but it does not seem to make a difference. The styling still breaks.

Comment: Review and see the the Bundling and Minification - ASP.NET MVC Demystified https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-bundling-and-minification/ written by Matthew Jones one of my favorite web developer.

Comment: it just seems wierd when setting the optimization to false, everything works perfectly...

Comment: bro, which browser are you using ?

Comment: If your thing is working fine then don't forget to vote me. :)

Comment: tested in chrome, firefox and edge. with same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195011/discussion-between-shahzad-khan-and-andrelange91).